# multiple return variables from graphical function in stateflow

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I'm using stateflow graphical function and one of my return parameters are not updated after exiting the function.

I'm using **matlab** as my default code language.

Is it possible to return more than one variable from a graphical function?

What is the correct way for returning more than one parameter from a graphical function?

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: `The syntax for calling a function with multiple outputs is exactly the same as in MATLAB`.

There are several examples of doing this in the documentation, including [Multi-Output Graphical Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/examples/multi-output-graphical-functions.html)